# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TranslateService -> TranslateStore]

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

I have the following structure

app.module.ts

```
    @ngModule({
       imports: [
           // other imports
               SharedModule,
               TranslateModule.forRoot({ 
                   loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: createTranslateLoader, deps: [HttpClient] } 
                })
       ],
       providers: [
           // other providers
           TranslateService
       ]
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

shared.module.ts

```
@ngModule({
   declarations: [MyComponent]
   imports: [
       // other imports
           AnotherComponentModule,
           TranslateModule.forChild()
   ],
   exports: [MyComponent]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

With this setup, I am getting the error

*ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TranslateService -> TranslateStore]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TranslateService -> TranslateStore]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateStore!*

The error started appearing when migrating from Angular 6 to Angular 8.

The error doesnt not appear in components inside that `AnotherComponentModule`, so somehow it's only in components declared directly in the `SharedModule`.

When I put the MyComponent in its own module and import it in sharedModule, things start working.

I have tried adding `TranslateService` and `TranslateStore` to `SharedModule` and also the module that contains the component using `MyComponent` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You need to import the HttpClientModule in your app.module

Try this:

```
   @ngModule({
   imports: [
           HttpClientModule
           SharedModule,
           TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
              deps: [HttpClient]
            }
          })
   ],
   providers: []
   })

export class AppModule { }
```